# What i must use to place image in bottom flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter code and a problem.I cant place an image with plus in bottom right.I tried to use align and marfin but this instruments dont help me.Maybe this problem can be solved by another instrument and I am no sure about it but can appbar changes the position of all images?

```
class _MainpageState extends State<_Mainpage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Copied Notes",
      home: new Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10,
                          left: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Notes",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1),
                            fontSize: 72,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 0),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        child: Text(
                          "Never Settle",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 0.25),
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 50),
                      Container(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/magnifier.png',
                            height: 22,
                            width: 22,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Container(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/3dot.png',
                            height: 22,
                            width: 22,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/plus.png',
                        height: 44,
                        width: 44,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(23, 34, 59, 1),
          appBar: PreferredSize(
              child: AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0))),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gARm0.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the Stack, it recommended using positioned widget like this :

```
Positioned(
      bottom: 0.0,
      right: 0.0,
      width: 44.0,
      height: 44.0,
      child: Image.asset('assets/images/magnifier.png'),
    ),
```

and you also can check the flutter team video on the positioned widget

Answer (score 0):

You can use a floating action button and by default its at the bottom right of the screen.

```
class _MainpageState extends State<_Mainpage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new MaterialApp(
  title: "Copied Notes",
  home: new Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10,
                      left: 10,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Notes",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1),
                        fontSize: 72,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 0),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    child: Text(
                      "Never Settle",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 0.25),
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 50),
                  Container(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text('test'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Container(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text('test')
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(23, 34, 59, 1),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          child: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0)),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/plus.png',
          height: 44,
          width: 44,
         )
      ),

    ),
  );
 }
}
```